# I am getting weird error 404 in IIS with page that don't exist

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I am compiling an asp.net application with VS 2010 in windows server 2012 . The application is running smoothly in local pc. When I try to compile it in server the following comes up

The resource cannot be found. 
  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /ccc/login.aspx
 My  start page is default.aspx  and in local pc I am able to run it smoothly.
I checked the permission and I have full rights in the folder. 
What I am doing wrong.?

Comment: What are your bindings for that site in IIS?

Comment: DId you give permission to IIS_IUSRS? Without that the IIS user doesn't have access to the documents

Comment: Does the page login.aspx exist or not?

Comment: log.aspx does not exists

Comment: IIS_IUSers what permission level should I give?

Comment: I am running it with binding at ppp.ccc.edu and port 80

Comment: When I try to give permsiion to IIS_Iuser  I am getting error as "Failed to enumerate objects in the coantainer Access is denied"

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps -

1. Go to IIS.
2. Select your web application.
3. Select 'Default Document' and check if Default.aspx is there or not.
4. If it is not there, add an entry.

Now try running your site. Also, you can enable 'Directory Browsing' for your applcation and select whatever page you want to run.

Comment: I  tried it before . I am running it now with vs 2010  in my server.  Getting same error as login.aspx does not exist

Comment: Try running like this - http://ppp.ccc.edu:8080/<your_application_folder>/default.aspx
It will directly hit your page, if accessible.

Comment: Are you hosting your application under default website? I guess it should be some error with your binding or the virtual directory. The URL is not pointing to the folder where you have deployed your application. @user1121727

Comment: I am initially running the application with visual studio in my server. I am getting that error  in localhost itself.

Comment: What are you using for deployment? Dev Server or IIS local or IIS Express?

Comment: dev server used for deployement

Comment: Can you plz post the link you are getting while running the page on browser??

Comment: The link is in server , still not given by DNS .

Comment: my initial question is why vs 2010 giving that login.aspx cannot be displayed when the page is not there in my  application?

Comment: http://localhost:50473/ccc/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fccc%2fDefault.aspx           The above is coming up when I am trying to debug it

Comment: You have forms authentication enabled in your application, right??

Comment: If you don't require it, disble it. The error will be gone.